# Get an overview report of Javadoc statistics

Tags: git, svn, javadoc

Is there a tool or process that can inspect the code in a repo like SVN or GIT and report back on how complete the Javadoc is? Basically I want to be able to get an overview of how completely a project has been documented.

I am aware the Ohloh provides a count of lines of comments and a ratio to lines of code, but I'm interested in getting statistics like x number of classes documented with Javadoc out of y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkstyle might have the ability to generate these results.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-verifier-plugin/checkstyle.html